# Accuracy of Timer1 as real time clock with PIC Interrupts on 16F*

Tags: c, timer, real-time, pic, microchip

I'm using C with the BoostC compiler. I'm worried how accurate my code is. The configuration below ticks at more or less 1Hz, (tested with an LED to the naked eye). (It uses an external watch crystal 32kHz for Timer1 on the 16f74).

I'm hoping someone can tell me...

Does my code below need any adjustments? What would be the easiest way of measuring the accuracy to the nearest CPU clock period? Will I need to get dirty with assembly to reliably ensure accuracy of the 1Hz signal?

I'm *hoping* the time taken to execute the timer handler (and others) doesn't even come into the picture, since the timer is always counting. So long as the handlers never take longer to execute than 1/32kHz seconds, will the 1Hz signal have essentially the accuracy of the 32kHz Crystal?

Thanks

```
#define T1H_DEFAULT 0x80
#define T1L_DEFAULT 0
volatile char T1H = T1H_DEFAULT;
volatile char T1L = T1L_DEFAULT;

void main(void){

    // setup 
    tmr1h = T1H;
    tmr1l = T1L;
    t1con = 0b00001111; // — — T1CKPS1 T1CKPS0 T1OSCEN NOT_T1SYNC TMR1CS TMR1ON
    // ...

    // do nothing repeatedly while no interrupt
    while(1){}
}

interrupt(void) {

    // Handle Timer1
    if (test_bit(pir1, TMR1IF) & test_bit(pie1, TMR1IE)){

            // reset timer's 2x8 bit value
            tmr1h = T1H;
            tmr1l = T1L;

            // do things triggered by this time tick

            //reset T1 interrupt flag 
            clear_bit(pir1, TMR1IF);

    } else 

    ... handle other interrupts

}
```

Comment: Here for we have http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see some improvements...

Your timer initiation inside interrupt isn't accurate.
When you set the timer counter in interrupt...

```
    tmr1h = T1H;
    tmr1l = T1L;
```

... then you override the current value what isn't good for accuracy.
... just use:

```
tmr1h = T1H;  //tmr1h  must be still 0!
```

Or even better, just set the 7th bit of tmr1h register.
The compiler must compile this order to single asm instruction like...

```
bsf    tmr1h, 7
```

...to avoid losing data in tmr1 register. Because if this is made with more than one instructions  the hardware can increment the counter value between execution of: read-modify-write.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you're saying, but since the timer is only being incremented at 32kHz, with a 4Mhz clock wouldn't that give me around 125 cycles in the ISR before a write to the timer values would be dirty?

Comment: You didn't tell us the main CPU frequency. If CPU clock is 4MHz than the inctruction cycle is 1MHz so this is only 30 inctruction clocks, and the interrupt latency can be much more than 30 inctruction clocks particularly if you handling more different interrupts.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I know this is now heading towards electronics territory, but please could you expand on what constitutes interrupt latency? Is it just the ISR code execution? Or is there some sort of additional hardware delay?

Comment: Of course there is some hardware delay, but this takes only a few program cycels. The main peoblem is if tmr1 overflow event is heppend when program executing another interrupt like UART interrupt or any other. In that situation the TMR1 overflow event is waiting that currently pending interrupt finish job and switch on interrupts again. After that next by hardware priority table waiting interrupt will be executed. Of course in the main time the tmr1 is running. So this situation can takes unpredictable number of CPU clocks.